# Missing Georeferencer

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing

I installed Qgis Master  64 bits on win7 64 16gb of ram and I am unable to locate the georeferencer. All other Gdal application are there, Gdal is active, but no georeferencer. I tried yesterday, tried also reinstall and also I anstalled again today. No georeferencer at all.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you activate in the plugins menu? `Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> Installed -> Georeferencer GDAL`

Comment: Related: [Georeferencing in QGIS 3.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274503/georeferencing-in-qgis-3-0)

Comment: I have no sucha a problem in 3.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable it in the plugins menu. Goto 'Plugins' > 'Manage and install plugins' > 'Installed'. Then make sure GDAL Georeferencer is ticked.

Comment: Thanks, I was used to see it without activating it in manage and install plugins. Now there is a little glitch, since after I invoke the georeferencer, the georeferencer appears, do not respond for a little moment and I have an error stating "bad allocation". After that i can play with the georeferencer.