# Georeferencing in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I just upgraded to QGIS 3.0 (OS X as well on Windows 10) and can not find out how to do some georeferencing. I am told by the software, that GDAL georeferencing is still installed and that I could not remove it, and that it should be in the category "raster". But I can not find it there, also not in other parts of the menu.

[image: screenshot GDAL georeferencing plugin]

new profile created, but the same issue...:

[image]

Comment: Is "GDAL Georeferencing" "active" in the plugin list? Tick the box next to the name in the plugin list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there is no clickable box next to "GDAL Georeferencing"...

Comment: That looks broken - there should be a tickbox next to it like you have with "DB Manager". Try creating a new profile from the settings menu - this gives you a clean QGIS setup (you won't lose your current one) - and see if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: thanks a lot. So I have created a new profile, but...again there is no clickable box...

Comment: Its not just the georeferencer - it seems all your core plugins except eVis have the same missing checkbox. Check the logs (View.. Panels.. Log Messages) I think you may need to report this as a QGIS issue.

Comment: Could accept one of the answers below?  It seems that the one with the video fixes your problem. Once an answer is accepted, it is the first answer seen on this Q&A page (and thus more helpful to the community)

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. The bug is in the box.

Place the box next to Georeferencer plugin and activate it:

[image]

Comment: I just clicked the empty space where the box should be, and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

A bug in your install.

[image]

You should be able to tick the box next to Georeferencer GDAL.

[image]

After which it will be in the Raster menu.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using QGIS 3.2 on Arch, you need to install gsl (GNU Scientific Library) before the geo-referencer plugin shows in the plugin list. See dependencies here https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/qgis/.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit confusing that you can't "uninstall" Georeferencer which I think, when I was first looking at QGIS3, I took to mean that it was installed and operational. I think there is a semantic/logic issue here. Does install mean that you've downloaded the plugin or that it's installed, that is, ready for use? The word missing in the plugin manager is activate. And the word "Search" appears right above the checkboxes for activation. Also when you're looking at "Not installed" plugin list, there is a blank spot to the left of the listed items where a checkbox might or might not be. For a seemingly simple window, a lot going uninstall (although some can't be), reinstall, upgrade; then lists of plugins and a settings icon mixed into the list. A very ambitious app and these minor UI inconsistencies are somewhat unavoidable. Thanks for the great app and all the hard work.

Searching for the item in the Plugin Manager sometimes changes the behavior of the check box.

Answer (score 2):

For me the Georeferencer is actually not listed in the plugins list.
Running QGIS 3.0.3 in Antergos.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But, then I clicked on "Installed," searched for "georeferencer" and the check box appeared for me to choose it to activate. It appears under Raster now.