# Georeference option not visible in QGIS 3.0 for French version

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.0 Girona Early Adopter Release. I used to use Raster-->Georeference--> ... to georeference images in QGIS 2.18 but now I can only see the `interactive georeferencing` option in my version. Where did it go?

Could it be because my version is the French release?

[image]

When I go to the plugins and search for `georef`, I don't have the option for `georeferencer GDAL` only `freehand raster georeferencer` is available.  I have the experimental plugins option ticked too.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with the English version of QGIS, the plugin `georeferencer GDAL` must be activated by checking the box next to its name in the list of extensions. The difference in the French version is that the plugin is called `Géoréférenceur GDAL`.

The issue lay in the fact that the plugin has been translated into French (`Géoréférenceur GDAL`) and the way the search tool works in QGIS it was not found with my simple search for `georef`. Letters with accents (`é`, `è`, `à`, etc) are treated differently than letters without accents (`e`, `a`, etc) in the search. I had the idea that the plugin might have a different name in the French version by reading this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274503/georeferencing-in-qgis-3-0) where it has a different name in what appears to be in German.

My search for `georef` turned up empty, but when I searched for `GDAL` or `géoréf` it showed up.

[image]

Comment: Seems like searching for a term with unaccented characters should return results that include accented characters as well. I made a feature request: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19187

Comment: @csk Thanks!  I was thinking about about making a feature request but didn't get around to it.